# Object stays in screen all time (DIV)

Tags: html

Ok so I want a specific div to stay in the corner of my html5 web page even when i scroll down.So it is just hanging in the corner so wgeb you scroll down the age it is still in the corner. Not in a fixed position, but stuck to your screen kind of. I want these divs to stay in the upper right corner even when I scroll it stays there.

```
 <div style="font-size:50px; color:brown;" id="allCount">0</div>
<div style="font-size:30px; color:brown;" id="apsCount">0</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what `position: fixed` is about.

Comment: Does not work. Just keeps the page from not scrolling way from that part of the page. Not it staying on the page as you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what position: fixed is about.

```
#cornerItem {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Try a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4zjym/ There is a gradient under the fixed element to show you, that you can actually scroll the content under the item.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. But how can i align it to the upper right? Do I increasing left?